# Is there an opportunity to check if iPhone is 3GS or 3G?

Tags: iphone

Is there an opportunity to check if iPhone is 3GS or 3G?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice) class.

Also, taking a look at [this](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/detecting-device-information-on-the-iphone/) blog post might help.

There is an [article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-determining-your-platform.ars) at ARS TECHNICA that can provide more info on determining exactly the iPhone model you have. It involves using [sysctlbyname](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) system call and considering the following information:

- iPhone1,1 (for the first gen iPhone)
- iPhone1,2 (for the 3G model)
- iPhone2,1 (for the 3GS model)
- iPod1,1 (first gen iPod touch)
- iPod2,1 (second gen iPod touch)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But with the UIDevice datatype you can't read the exactly model number 3GS or 3G or even 2G.

Comment: Take a look at the new article I linked.